# Powershell: Pipe Get-ChildItem results to Compress-Archive to generate multiple zips?

Tags: powershell

Say I have the following folders

```
c:\test\folder1
c:\test\folder2
c:\test\folder3
```

And I want to create the following archives

```
c:\test\folder1.zip
c:\test\folder2.zip
c:\test\folder3.zip
```

**Can I somehow pipe `Get-ChildItem -name folder* -directory` to `compress-archive`?**

I tried `Get-ChildItem -name folder* -Directory | Compress-Archive -Verbose` but it tried to output to a single zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ForEach-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -name folder* -Directory | ForEach-Object -Process { Compress-Archive $_ $_ -Verbose }
```

Comment: Can you explain the two `$_`'s? Is that just passing the folder name twice to the Compress-Archive command which adds .zip if not specified?

Comment: The `$_` is the object in the `For-Each`, the first is for `Compress-Archive` path (what will be zipped), and the second is for the destination, if you not put `.zip` is add it automatically.

Comment: Right, so it's calling `Compress-Archive folder1 folder1`.  Got it.

Comment: @ScottBeeson Exactly :)